# Абсолютное позиционирование и Bootstrap сетка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, необходимо спозиционировать .submenu абсолютно, но при задании атрибута left по величине близком к размерам .col-md-3, видимо родительский bootstrap контейнер .col-md-3 ограничивает ширину элемента до минимальной. Необходимо, чтобы ширина "абсолютного" блока формировалась исходя из контента. Как это сделать? примерная картина

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu-header">menu</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item parent">
                    <a href="#">Item #111</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 001 sdfsdfsdfs</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 002</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 003</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #111</a></li>

            </ul>
```

полная картина:
https://jsfiddle.net/9m6ahw1n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понял что вам надо было полный код https://jsfiddle.net/9m6ahw1n/2/ ?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu-header">menu</div>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item parent">
                    <a href="#">Item #111</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 001 sdfsdfsdfs</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 002</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#">subitem 003</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Item #111</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

UPD
 Вариант 2 https://jsfiddle.net/9m6ahw1n/6/

```
.submenu {
position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
z-index: 200;
    padding: 0;
        width: 100%; // На всю ширину.  добавил
```

}
Как можно заметить уперлись мы в размер все равно родителя (.menu .menu-item > a), это 230px.

UPD 3 вариант ваш как и хотели позиционировать и абсолют + по контенту размера но но мы не можем превысить размер нашего родителя https://jsfiddle.net/9m6ahw1n/7/

Comment: Прекрасное решение, спасибо, но мне необходимо, чтобы ширина "абсолютного" блока формировалась исходя из внутреннего контента, а не принудительно

Comment: Не мне судить ваш стиль и задумку, но мне кажется плохая идея будет, так как у вас размер каждого пункта будет прыгать. и все равно вернетесь к фиксированому элементу.

Comment: Ваше решение https://jsfiddle.net/9m6ahw1n/7/